# A linear recursion with power coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recursion

In my research, I encounter a linear recursion of the form:
$$a_n = (AB^n+C)a_{n-1}-AB^na_{n-2},$$
where $A,B,C$ are all positive (arbitrary) constants such that $B,C>1$.

Is it possible to get a non-recursive formula for $a_n$? It does not have to be closed-form, but I want to get rid of the recursion (to be able to estimate the convergence rate of $a_n$).

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: Convergence rate? Isn't it so, that $a_n$ will most likely run away to infinity?

Comment: Assuming generic initial conditions: defining $b_n = a_n A^{-n}B^{-n(n+1)/2}$ yields the equivalent recursion $$b_n = b_{n-1} + \frac C{AB^n} b_{n-1} - \frac1{AB^{n-1}} b_{n-2},$$which suggests that $\{b_n\}$ converges to a constant $\beta$ and thus that $a_n \sim \beta A^n B^{n(n+1)/2}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! That's exactly what I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $a_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}K(t)~dt$ ,

Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}K(t)~dt=(AB^n+C)\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{(n-1)t}K(t)~dt-AB^n\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{(n-2)t}K(t)~dt$

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}K(t)~dt=A\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{n(t+1)}B^{-t}K(t)~dt+C\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}B^{-t}K(t)~dt-A\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{n(t+1)}B^{-2t}K(t)~dt$

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}K(t)~dt-A\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}B^{-t+1}K(t-1)~dt-C\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}B^{-t}K(t)~dt+A\int_{-\infty}^\infty B^{nt}B^{-2t+2}K(t-1)~dt=0$

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty((1-CB^{-t})K(t)+A(B^{-2t+2}-B^{-t+1})K(t-1))B^{nt}~dt=0$

$\therefore(1-CB^{-t})K(t)+A(B^{-2t+2}-B^{-t+1})K(t-1)=0$

$(1-CB^{-t})K(t)=A(B^{-t+1}-B^{-2t+2})K(t-1)$

$(B^{2t}-CB^t)K(t)=A(B^{t+1}-B^2)K(t-1)$

$K(t)=\dfrac{A(B^{t+1}-B^2)}{B^{2t}-CB^t}K(t-1)$

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. But would a closed-form formula be possible for K(t)? Otherwise, it is not really easier to deal with than the original recursion.